# How to make LangChain's chatbot answer only from the knowledge base I provided? It shouldn't have access to OpenAI's GPT-3.5 knowledge base

Tags: python, openai-api, langchain, py-langchain

I have the following chatbot which answers questions about the knowledge base `docs` and retrieves the source documents it got its answers from.

```
import os
from langchain.embeddings.openai import OpenAIEmbeddings
from langchain.vectorstores import FAISS
from langchain.chains import RetrievalQA
from langchain.memory import ConversationBufferMemory
from langchain.chat_models import ChatOpenAI
from langchain.prompts import PromptTemplate
from langchain.agents import AgentExecutor, Tool,initialize_agent
from langchain.agents.types import AgentType

os.environ['OPENAI_API_KEY'] = ''

system_message = """
"You are the XYZ bot."
"This is conversation with a human. Answer the questions you get based on the knowledge you have."
"If you don't know the answer, just say that you don't, don't try to make up an answer."
"""

llm = ChatOpenAI(
    model_name="gpt-3.5-turbo",  # Name of the language model
    temperature=0  # Parameter that controls the randomness of the generated responses
)

embeddings = OpenAIEmbeddings()

docs = [
    "Buildings are made out of brick",
    "Buildings are made out of wood",
    "Buildings are made out of stone",
    "Buildings are made out of atoms",
    "Buildings are made out of building materials",
    "Cars are made out of metal",
    "Cars are made out of plastic",
  ]

vectorstore = FAISS.from_texts(docs, embeddings)

retriever = vectorstore.as_retriever()

memory = ConversationBufferMemory(memory_key="chat_history", input_key='input', return_messages=True, output_key='output')

qa = RetrievalQA.from_chain_type(
        llm=llm,
        chain_type="stuff",
        retriever=vectorstore.as_retriever(),
        verbose=True,
        return_source_documents=True
    )

tools = [
        Tool(
            name="doc_search_tool",
            func=qa,
            description=(
               "This tool is used to retrieve information from the knowledge base"
            )
        )
    ]

agent = initialize_agent(
        agent = AgentType.CHAT_CONVERSATIONAL_REACT_DESCRIPTION,
        tools=tools,
        llm=llm,
        memory=memory,
        return_source_documents=True,
        return_intermediate_steps=True,
        agent_kwargs={"system_message": system_message}
        )
```

currently, if the query is something like "who is the president of the USA?", it answers the question when this information wasn't provided in `docs`. It even retrieves source documents which does not make sense.

```
query = "who is the president of the USA?"
result = agent(query)
```

I want the chatbot to answer something like "Sorry, I wasn't provided with information that answers your question" when the question's answer is not from the knowledge base.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define proper prompt role so that there is guided response from LLMs

```
"""As an AI assistant you provide answers based on the given context, ensuring accuracy and brifness. 

        You always follow these guidelines:

        -If the answer isn't available within the context, state that fact
        -Otherwise, answer to your best capability, refering to source of documents provided
        -Only use examples if explicitly requested
        -Do not introduce examples outside of the context
        -Do not answer if context is absent
        -Limit responses to three or four sentences for clarity and conciseness"""
```

Comment: I did that, but I still get an answer and source documents.

"As of my knowledge cutoff date in 2021, the President of the United States is Joe Biden. However, please note that this information may change over time, so it's always a good idea to verify with the latest sources."

Comment: You can tweak the prompt role, and explicitly mention that only answer from source documents.

Answer (score 0):

```
retriever=vectorstore.as_retriever(search_type="similarity_score_threshold", search_kwargs={
                              'score_threshold': 0.5})
```

Try with this parameter, works for me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).